# How to test application integration with Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, testing, google-cloud-platform, mocking, google-cloud-storage

I have an application that's integrated with Google Cloud Storage. I need to write some unit/integration tests to test my application with Google Cloud Storage.

I found a [MockGoogleCredential](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/testing/auth/oauth2/MockGoogleCredential.html) class for Java that simulates the credentials provider, but I could not find any code examples. Has anyone used this before?

Comment: With which framework do you perform test? How do you usually mock a class? With what?

Answer (score 3):

The gsutil test command explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/test) can be used to run the gsutil unit tests and integration tests. The unit tests use an in-memory mock storage service implementation, while the integration tests send requests to the production service using the preferred API set in the boto configuration file, view [gsutil help apis](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CloudStorageAPIs) for more details.

In addition, I came across [Google In-Memory emulator](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/TESTING.md#testing-code-that-uses-storage), but according to some Stackoverflow posts this has been moved to [here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage-nio).

There are also some non-official options been developed, such as [this one](https://github.com/fsouza/fake-gcs-server) which you could use for stubbing/mocking Google Cloud Storage as a standalone server.

Finally, while navigating through related GitHub Feature Requests, I came across [this](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) unofficial library which includes integration tests and supports GCS, according to [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5816) GitHub issue.